# How to find "NFC Tag Identifier" in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

I am using "CoreNFC" framework to detect NFC Tags
Here I am facing issue related Identifying "NFC Tag Identifier"

In Android, 
can get access it from:

```
/**
     * Optional extra containing a byte array containing the ID of the discovered tag for
     * the {@link #ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED}, {@link #ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED}, and
     * {@link #ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED} intents.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "android.nfc.extra.ID";
```

Do we have any similar way in iOS?

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/corenfc-introduction/ Check this link.

Comment: more useful link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-scan-nfc-tags-using-core-nfc.

Comment: Hey @KetanOdedra Thanks. But here in both tutorial they are showing "How to access NFC tags", which I am able to do. I want to know how to access NFC Tag Identifier!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what type of tags. For native tag reading on iOS (ISO15693, NFCMiFareTag, NFCISO7816Tag, etc) you can convert the detected tag to the appropriate model object where you can get the identifier.

These resources helped:
https://swifting.io/blog/2019/07/11/53-first-steps-with-nfc-on-ios-13/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso15693tag?language=objc

Comment: How to get this detected tag? NDEF delegate provides only NDEF messages.

Comment: You can use NFCTagReaderSession. The first link I provided will help you.

Comment: I was working on Xamarin platform with `INFCTagReaderSessionDelegateand` interface witch do not have `DidDetectTags` callback. But then I notice that there is also concrete class implementation `NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate`. All are good now. Tnx!

Comment: Link has gone dead unfortunately